# Working with user input and dictionaries inside of lists

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

Coming to the close of week 1 learning a programming language (Python)

Looking for general review, comments, and tips

**Objective of Code**

The objective here was to practice pulling information from dictionaries within lists and also adding dictionaries created from user input.

**Code**

```
def make_album(artist, album, tracks =''):
    catalog = {}
    catalog['artist_name'] = artist
    catalog['album_title'] = album
    catalog['tracks'] = tracks

    return catalog

def ask_user(message):
    user_input =''
    while not user_input:
        user_input = input(message)
    return user_input

riven = make_album('Zeppelin', 'Houses of the Holy', 8)
jax = make_album('Tool', 'Lateralus', 13)
vayne = make_album('Pink Floyd', 'Dark Side of the Moon')

differents = [riven, jax, vayne]

while True:
    print("type q to quit")
    band = ask_user("Enter artist: ")
    if band == "q":
        break
    album = ask_user("Enter album: ")
    if album == 'q':
        break
    numbers = input("Enter number of tracks: ")
    if numbers == 'q':
        break
    fire = make_album(band.title(), album.title(), numbers)
    differents.append(fire) 


for i in differents:
    if i['tracks']:
        print('\n' + i['album_title'] + ' by ' \
            + i['artist_name'] + ' it has '\
            + str(i['tracks']) +' tracks.')
    else:
        print('\n' +  i['album_title'] + ' by ' + i['artist_name'] \
            + '.')
```

**Output**

```
vash@localhost:~/pcc/8$ python3 lot2learn.py
type q to quit
Enter artist: circa survive
Enter album: juturna
Enter number of tracks: 11
type q to quit
Enter artist: dance gavin dance
Enter album: happiness
Enter number of tracks:
type q to quit
Enter artist: q

Houses of the Holy by Zeppelin it has 8 tracks.

Lateralus by Tool it has 13 tracks.

Dark Side of the Moon by Pink Floyd.

Juturna by Circa Survive it has 11 tracks.

Happiness by Dance Gavin Dance .
(xenial)vash@localhost:~/pcc/8$
```

Comment: @Graipher when you have time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should put all code that isn't in a function in a `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard. So that it doesn't run when it shouldn't.
2. You can simplify quitting by using exceptions. If you make a function that raises say `KeyboardInterupt` if the input is `'q'` then you can reduce the amount of code needed.
3. I like to not use variables when they're not needed, or increase readability, and so you may want to move `riven` straight into the creation of `differents`.
4. You can use f-strings or `str.format` to build your prints for you:

   ```
   >>> i = {'title': 'title', 'album': 'album'}
   >>> i['title'] + ' by ' + i['album']
   'title by album'
   >>> "{i[title]} by {i[album]}".format(i=i)
   'title by album'
   # Python 3.6+
   >>> f"{i['title']} by {i['album']}"
   'title by album'
   ```
5. You can simplify `make_album` by using dictionary sugar:

   ```
   def make_album(artist, album, tracks =''):
       return {
           'artist_name': artist,
           'album_title': album,
           'tracks': tracks
       }
   ```
6. You can alturnatly use `collections.namedtuple`:

   ```
   # Python 3.7
   Album = collections.namedtuple('Album', 'artist album tracks', defaults=('',))

   # Otherwise
   Album = collections.namedtuple('Album', 'artist album tracks')


   def make_album(artist, album, tracks=''):
       return Album(artist, album, tracks)
   ```
7. I'd create a couple more functions. But honestly your code is pretty great. Half my suggestions I wouldn't expect a beginner to use.

```
import collections

Album = collections.namedtuple('Album', 'artist album tracks', defaults=('',))


def ask_user(message):
    user_input = None
    while not user_input:
        user_input = input(message)
    return user_input


def check_quit(user_input):
    if user_input == 'q':
        raise KeyboardInterupt()
    return user_input


def get_additional_albums():
    albums = []
    try:
        print("type q to quit")
        while True:
            albums.append(Album(
                cheack_quit(ask_user("Enter artist: ")).title(),
                cheack_quit(ask_user("Enter album: ")).title(),
                cheack_quit(input("Enter number of tracks: "))
            ))
    except KeyboardInterupt:
        pass
    return albums


if __name__ == '__main__':
    differents = [
        Album('Zeppelin', 'Houses of the Holy', 8),
        Album('Tool', 'Lateralus', 13),
        Album('Pink Floyd', 'Dark Side of the Moon')
    ]
    differents += get_additional_albums()

    for i in differents:
        output = f'{i.title} by {i.album}'
        if i.tracks:
            output = f'{output} it has {i.tracks} tracks'
        print(f'\n{output}.')
```

Comment: Thank you! All this is so exciting, every time you suggested new ways to write code that I never seen, or new commands, my eyes light up ha it gives me something new to learn, understand, and integrate, I want to write super clean and simplified code. All this is greatly appreciated I will not let it go to waste. That dictionary sugar you mentioned omg thats sick, using that everytime.

Comment: unsure how to format comments with newlines  but would you suggest something like this for the `differents` `differents =[]
differents.append(make_album('Zeppelin', 'Houses of the Holy', 8))
differents.append(make_album('Tool', 'Lateralus', 13))
differents.append(make_album('Pink Floyd', 'Dark Side of the Moon'))`

Comment: @vash_the_stampede That's good to hear! :) I'd not use that, as you have to type `differents` a lot, and it doesn't read as nice

Comment: hmm for now I suppose I could write a function that appends to differents and then call that function for now, would be cleaner, I just want to elimate those variables as you said, but going to learn your way and then apply that !

Comment: @vash_the_stampede You could just use `differents = [a, b, c]` such as in my answer (and your question) :)

Comment: yes thank you again, I will get this down, and my next code will be better, can't wait to share!

Comment: sorry to blow you up but man I can't over the dictionary sugar, how awesome is that, that is blowing my mind I love it hahahah